# Elementary proof of d(circular segment area)/ d(circular segment length) = radius?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

It is easy to use calculus to find that in a circular segment, if the chord is held constant, then
$$\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial s}\right)_c = R$$
Where $c$ is the chord, held constant, $a$ is area of circular segment and $s$ is arc length. Is there an elementary geometric argument for this?

[image: Figure]

Comment: The problem is contradictory because a cord couldn’t be held constant when evaluating a limit where the cord length becomes infinitesimal.
Aside of that, I think that there isn’t a geometric proof that circumvents infinitesimals, hence calculus. If it existed, it would involve operating with the exact value of  $\pi$ which can not be determined exactly outside calculus.

Comment: Notations like $\frac{\partial a}{\partial s}$ work only if we have a very clear idea of what function(s) we are working with. In what specific way are you finding the area $a$ as a function of $s$ and other variables? It would help if you wrote the formula out explicitly; this would help people understand what you mean by $\frac{\partial a}{\partial s}$. I might be able to guess what you're thinking, but it would be more straightforward for you to say it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried approximating the circular wedge as two triangles?

Comment: @DavidK how about now

Comment: We already had "the chord is held constant". What I'm having trouble with is writing the area as an explicit function of $c$ and $s.$ If I actually set $c$ as a constant, so that segment length and area become functions of a single variable, for example the height of the segment, I can derive your result using total derivatives, but it was a complicated, laborious derivation and I could only get to the result by knowing what I was looking for. I got no intuition from it. You say you "easily" found your result; I'm wondering how. It might yield some clues.

Comment: I used $\theta$ as the variable, and wrote $a, s$ as functions of $\theta, c$, then just bruteforced $a(\theta + d\theta, c), c(\theta + d\theta, c)$. This was enough for Wolfram Alpha to verify the result. But that's not how I found the result. I found the result by solving the isoperimetric problem with Lagrangian multipliers, and interpreting one of the multipliers as a shadow price for the length of the curve.